# Disabling progress bar when URL fetch completes: A standard scenario

Tags: android, android-fragments, retrofit

I have a rather popular scenario in which there is a fragment containing a progress bar and a ListView. I'd like to populate the ListView after fetching the data using Retrofit. Now, the progress bar needs to be made invisible once a response comes back in.

Would it be a good idea to store the view of the fragment layout inflated in `onCreateView()` as a member variable and use that variable to disable the progress bar in `onResponse()` (the callback is created in `onCreate()`), when the fetch succeeds?

Fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
                android:id="@+id/source_items_list"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:padding="5dp">


    <com.gc.materialdesign.views.ProgressBarCircularIndeterminate
            android:id="@+id/progress_bar"
            android:layout_width="32dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp"
            android:background="#1E88E5"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"/>

    <ListView android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:id="@+id/source_list"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

onCreate():

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mItemList = new ArrayList<SourceItem>();

    RestClient.get().getSources().enqueue(new Callback<SourceItemList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<SourceItemList> response, Retrofit retrofit) {

            if (response.isSuccess()) {

                disableProgressBar();

                //...
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            disableProgressBar();
            return;
        }

        private void disableProgressBar() {
            if (mView != null) {
                mView.findViewById(R.id.progress_bar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });

    // ...
}
```

onCreateView():

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup viewGroup, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_sourceitem_list, viewGroup, false);
    // ...

    return mView;
}
```

Thanks

Comment: I suggest rather than keeping view just make progress bar as member variable, init it onViewCreated of fragment and do what ever you want to do with that progress bar variable.

Comment: I see. But how come? Is it more memory intensive to keep the reference to the view? Shouldn't it be fairly light though?

Comment: actually in term of memory :  yes for now it is almost same but lets say you have some new components in your xml then it is memory intensive and gc will called once onDestroyView of fragment is triggered, there might be a chance that OS will kill you app due to memory church when it is background.

Answer (score 1):

It is better to have progress bar initialized in onCreateView() rather than using view.findViewById() as it's an expensive operation.

Comment: findViewById is not at all expensive operation. its a id which has been generated by R.java and android maintain a hash which there there is 1 to 1 mapping, so ideally its O(1) operation.

Comment: @dex I think it traverses through the view hierarchy until it finds a matching id. And that's the reason it's not good idea to do that each time one needs a reference to a view. Better to have a local variable and use that whenever needed.

Comment: you mean android store the view in the form of tree may be balance one and do traverse using bfs or dfs ? Please share relevant link too if possible. Thanks a lot for the clarification.

Comment: but going through findViewById code from here http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/View.java#View.findViewById%28int%29 it doesn't give impression that it has some tree form of view and they are not doing bfs or dfs to find out value.

Comment: @dex It certainly *is* a tree & traversal. From your link,"View IDs need not be unique throughout the *tree*, but it is good practice to ensure that they are at least unique within the part of the *tree* you are searching."   `findViewById` calls is `findViewTraversal`. What you are missing is that `View`s are leaves in the tree, just look there, it appears O(1), but `ViewGroup`s (parent class of layouts),  shows it recursively calls `findViewById` on all its children. http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.4.4_r1/android/view/ViewGroup.java#3246

Comment: Thanks a lot @iagreen for detail explanation :)